# Zend Framework - Different layouts with different contents

Tags: zend-framework, layout, mobile

In the project I'm working I had to do two versions of the website, a desktop one and a mobile one. In order to do that I had to use the **wurfl** library and I created a frontController plugin called `Plugins_Context`.

In that class, in the method `dispatchLoopStartup` I check if the device is a mobile I load another layout `Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('mobile');`. This load **application/layouts/scripts/mobile.phtml** with the new mobile layout, the problem I have is when I call `$this->layout()->content` it loads content from the regular view, I need to load the content for a new mobile view.

Thanks!

Comment: where are you setting `content` and how?

Comment: Hi. I'm new with Zend Framework, not sure where I can set that. It is in some file of the controller folder?

Comment: Ok well, _somewhere_ in your code you must have something like `$this->view->layout()->content = 'content';`. So, I am asking you where it is and what you're using to set content. For example, you might be rendering a view script like so: `$this->view->layout()->content = $this->view->render('path/to/script.phtml');`.  You get it now?

Comment: Do you have separate view scripts as well for the mobile and regular users?  These are separate view scripts aside from the layout?

Comment: mmmshuddup: Not sure where is that. Where should be that?
drew010: I have two layouts right now normal.phtml and mobile.phtml and I want to load different views for each layout.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you resolve this i have similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem and what I did was to not use

```
$this->layout()->content;
```

and call different actions from the different layouts like -

```
$this->action('index', 'index','main');
```

and

```
$this->action('index_mobile', 'index','main');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, how do I use that? That should be called in the layout file instead of **$this->layout()->content;**? And what mean index, index and main?

Comment: yes, call that in layout instead of  $this->layout()->content, the first index is the action name, second the controller name and the third is the module name, u have to write to different actions for mobile and webpage. u see $this->layout()->content calls the default action, you can stop that and can call your own.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem using the code below

**Using**

```
 $mobile     =   $this->request->getControllerName() . "/" . $this->request->getActionName() . ".mobile.phtml";
echo $this->partial($mobile,$params);
```

**Instead of**

```
echo $this->layout()->content;
```

consider you have all mobile templates having .mobile as suffix in the name